# How to clear session if internet is disconnected?

Tags: javascript, php, session

I want to clear the session value if the internet disconnect in javascript. I am working on a financial transaction project, so there is need more security. If internet disconnect or reconnect then session should be clear or expired.

This is my session value

```
$_SESSION["email"];
```

Comment: I want to clear it at the client side, at the browser.

Comment: You can make use of `navigator.onLine`. and agreed with jaromandaX

Comment: I am trying to clear session by ajax, but when connection lost then ajax does not work then session does not clear. How to clear the session in java script?

Comment: I have described the session value by editing the post, Check it

Comment: Ok, So what can we do for that? Is there any option for solving this?

Comment: does `$_SESSION` not empty by default on disconnecting? By default, server conf is 24 mins expiry - but if user disconnects from said server, they have no session to connect to?

Comment: In our environment (not PHP) a session is dropped when there hasn't been any activity for 30 minutes. For the majority of our clients, they are quite happy with that, but there's always one, right, that wants a far shorter "kill" time. So, because the session "life" can't be configured per client, we implemented a "heartbeat" - a simple AJAX request every minute or so ... and on the server side, if a session from the "problem" client didn't get a heartbeat in the last 5 minutes, the session is invalidated - problem solved

Comment: I would've added that above as an answer, but it's not really helpful enough unless you can understand the concept and translate it to PHP code - as I haven't touched PHP in many years, I can't even begin to help with that part

Comment: The issue with `If internet disconnect or reconnect then session should be clear or expired` is that the server can not tell if a client has had a momentary (even minutes long) disruption of internet connection - unless you write your website in such a way that there is a required connection always in place between client and server (i.e. websocket perhaps) - momentary disconnections on websockets I believe can be detected

Answer (score 1):

If the internet disconnects, you won't have access to the server.

Secondly, Javascript cannot access PHP.

However, Javascript can delete the session **cookie**.

In plain JS, something like this:

```
function delete_cookie( name, path, domain ) {
  if( get_cookie( name ) ) {
    document.cookie = name + "=" +
      ((path) ? ";path="+path:"")+
      ((domain)?";domain="+domain:"") +
      ";expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT";
  }
}
```

Or in jQuery:

```
$.cookie('foo', null, {path: '/'});
```

If it's an HTTP only cookie, then you won't be able to delete it.

You'll need to disable HTTP only in your PHP settings with

```
session.cookie_httponly = 0
```

But that introduces some security risks, so choose wisely wether you actually need this or not.